# How do you manipulate a void pointer passed as a parameter in a variadic function in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, variadic-functions

I have the following variadic function (a version of `vsprintf`):

```
buf[size] = '0'; size++;                
buf[size] = 'x'; size++;
void **ptr = va_arg(arg, void *);
num = unsigned_to_base(&buf[size], bufsize, (int)*ptr, HEX_BASE, 8);
```

where the function `unsigned_to_base()` takes in a hexadecimal number and places it as a string in `buf` (the `0x` prefix must be placed manually as the function doesn't automatically.
`unsigned_to_base` functions as follows:

`int unsigned_to_base(char *buf, size_t bufsize, unsigned int val, int base, int min_width)`
where `buf` is the destination, `bufsize` is the size of `buf`, `val` is the value in question, `base` is the base number system to express the string as (in this case it is base 16, hex), and `min_width` is the minimum width of the output string, padding the front with leading 0s if needed. The function returns the number of characters written to `buf`.

The parameter I am extracting in the variadic function is `(void *) 0x20200004` and I am trying to return `"0x20200004"`. However, the actual return value I am receiving is `"0x00012000"`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, compiling with `-fsanitize=address` crashes the program, tells me exactly which line it went wrong, and what happened (dereferencing 0x20200004). It's a great tool that requires only one extra debug flag to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`va_arg` returns a value of the type given as a parameter. Your `va_arg` returns a `void*`, but you're storing it in a `void**`, which I don't think is what you want. Also, I see you have the C++ tag, so why are you using variadic lists in C++ anyway?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `unsigned_to_base` you dereference `ptr`, which gives you the value at the address 0x20200004. You instead want the value 0x20200004, so don't dereference:

```
num = unsigned_to_base(&buf[size], bufsize, (int)ptr, HEX_BASE, 8);
```